# Причина предупреждения при работе с Lottie Swift 5

Tags: swift

Причина предупреждения при работе с Lottie Swift 5. Как можно это решить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас все работает и вы не собираетесь становиться контрибьютором этого проекта - не трогайте.

Если хотите все же внести исправление в саму библиотеку, добавьте case default (и его обработку) в switch оператор. Предупреждение говорит что case может покрывать не все возможные варианты содержимого переменной contentMode.

---

Чтобы прятать warnings в используемых Pod библиотеках:

Добавьте в ваш Podfile:

```
platform :ios

# Для отключения всех предупреждений из Pod:
inhibit_all_warnings!

# Для отключения предупреждений в конкретной библиотеки:
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', :inhibit_warnings => true
```

Затем выполните:

```
pod install
```

Comment: Спасибо! Да, всё работает) Просто неприятно когда горит предупреждение)

Comment: @AndreyVelin Да, понимаю, я сам такой. Я обновил ответ, если вы используете CocoaPods, можно спрятать warnings.

Comment: Ваня, доброй ночи! Помоги пожалуйста если знаешь ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/969345/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-json-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA-lottie

Comment: @AndreyVelin отметьте пожалуйста вопрос, как отвеченный, если проблема решена.