# Как менять размер анимации json фреймворк Lottie?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Как менять размер анимации json фреймворк Lottie? Изначально загруженный json выглядит маленьким, а мне нужно изменить размер. Помогите пожалуйста.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас просто не указан размер.
Для изменения размера поменяйте значение переменной size.

```
import UIKit
import Lottie

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let animationView = AnimationView()
    let size: CGFloat = 500

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let animation = Animation.named("5438")
        animationView.animation = animation
        animationView.play()
        animationView.loopMode = .loop

        animationView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size, height: size)
        animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill           
        view.addSubview(animationView)

        animationView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        animationView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        animationView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size).isActive = true
        animationView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size).isActive = true
        animationView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

    }

}
```

[image: Animation]

Comment: Спасибо! Топ чел

Comment: Ваня, а как сделать анимацию не по центру, а сверху?

Comment: @AndreyVelin Используйте Auto Layout. Я дополнил ответ.

Comment: У меня размер анимации не меняется :(

Comment: @AndreyVelin Покажите ваш код. Можно скопировать сюда: https://gist.github.com

Comment: Вот: https://yadi.sk/i/eoKdZZGyRJYUUw

Comment: Ваня, у тебя есть Telegram? Может я там буду тебя спрашивать?

Comment: @AndreyVelin Размер let size: CGFloat = 2000 это очень много. У вас экран на телефоне скорее всего меньше. Попробуйте указать не такое большое значение.

Comment: @AndreyVelin Лучше в будущем выкладывайте код в виде текста. В более сложных случаях это позволит воспроизвести проблему.

Comment: @AndreyVelin Лучше пишите сюда или создавайте тут новые вопросы, я смотрю их каждый день. Если я буду отвечать в телеграмме, я вам помогу, но другие пользователи не смогут увидеть и применить это решение для своей аналогичной проблемы.

Comment: Пробовал указывать любое значение, не работает :(

Comment: @AndreyVelin посмотрел еще раз, в вашем коде отсутствует строка animationView.animation = animation

Comment: Всё равно анимация стоит по середине, это когда animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit, а если ставишь animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill то изображение становится сверху, но часть анимации обрезается (даже когда меняю размер).

Comment: @AndreyVelin как именно вы хотите расположить анимацию? Нет никакой необходимости делать contentMode = .scaleAspectFill, все параметры можно выставить через constraints

Comment: Хочу, чтобы анимация была сверху как я выстроил UIView:https://yadi.sk/i/A_RjLKAppahB6g. А это с тем кодом, что ты сверху писал. 1) animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill: https://yadi.sk/i/KzfomGYr99U5lA 2) animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit: https://yadi.sk/i/n2RZEQpGE7-TKA . В итоге я хочу,чтобы анимация была прибита к верху и чтобы я мог менять её размер

Comment: @AndreyVelin Такое ощущение что у вашей анимации пустой участок сверху (прямо в файле). Если это так, вы можете поменять constant: 0 на constant: -50 например, в строке animationView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

Comment: Спасиибо! ОЧень выручил!!!

Comment: Ваня, а почему при добавлении таблицы, она отображается нормально только на 5-ых айфонах? Как будто что то ограничивает таблицу: https://yadi.sk/i/ox6Mp7iO9do36g, https://yadi.sk/i/tP73jwT7zxf75g

Comment: А что не так с таблицей? Вы используете Auto Layout для таблицы?

Comment: Вот видео: https://yadi.sk/i/rUs8yhdUPI0EQg. Таблица закреплена констрейтами

Comment: Что не так? Таблица находится ниже анимации, вы можете поднять ее выше, если надо. Если не хотите чтобы работала прокрутка - отключите ее.

Comment: А как её выше поднять? Я этого хочу

Comment: Я к тому, что я даже на SE не могу нажать на нужную мне ячейку, как будто что-то перекрывает: https://yadi.sk/i/6Xu-oK8PfGz0cw

Comment: view.bringSubviewToFront(tableView)